# python regex of group match

Tags: python, regex

Here is my code:

```
import re

pattern_str = '(?P<style>[^|]*>)\|(?P<tags>[^|]*)'

p = re.compile(pattern_str)

m = p.match('OL|AAAAA')
a = m.group('style')  # AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
print a
```

It doesn't work, how to fix it?

My python version is  2.6.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `>` in the `style` pattern:

```
pattern_str = '(?P<style>[^|]*)\|(?P<tags>[^|]*)'
```

Comment: @sashimi: You're welcome; and hey, a typo happens to everyone ;)

Comment: @sashimi - this is the part where you click the checkmark to mark this as the answer to your question.