# python regex: match a group more than once

Tags: python, regex, quantifiers, regex-group

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python regular expressions - how to capture multiple groups from a wildcard expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464736/python-regular-expressions-how-to-capture-multiple-groups-from-a-wildcard-expr)
>   [python regex of group match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026100/python-regex-of-group-match)

I know there are better or easier ways to do this, but as I tried it myself and it did not work I am interested why, so here is the problem:

Assume I want to get Xml attributes with a regex. Lets look at the following XML-Node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Node key1="val1" key2="val2">
    <OtherNode>
        <!-- something -->
    </OtherNode>
</Node>
```

to parse the `Node` as well as `OtherNode` I have the following regex:

```
import re
pattern=re.compile
('\s*?<(?P<key>[\w\d]+?)
  \s*?(?P<meta>(?P<metakey>[\w:]+?)="(?P<metavar>.+?)"\s*)*>')
```

the output of `pattern.findall(xml)` is:

> ('Node', 'key2="val2"', 'key2', 'val2')
>   ('OtherNode', '', '', '')

and the output of `[m.groupdict() for m in pattern.finditer(xml)]`:

```
{'metakey': 'key2', 'meta': 'key2="val2"', 'metavar': 'val2', 'key': 'Node'}
{'metakey': None, 'meta': None, 'metavar': None, 'key': 'OtherNode'}
```

It seems like only the last metavar is accesible as group.

How to match `key1` as well as `key2`? Isn't it possible to match more than one group with the `(...)*` construct? In other words: I want the regex to match the named group `meta` more than once if present.

Comment: If you want to _parse xml_, considering using a XML parser like [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/)

Comment: Thats what I mentioned first: I KNOW there are xml parsers, just wondering why I cannot match a group more than once

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464736/python-regular-expressions-how-to-capture-multiple-groups-from-a-wildcard-expr

Comment: @hayden you ever heard of lazyQuantifiers? `*` is a `greedy` quantifier where `*?` and `+?`are indicated lazy by the `?` after them. read the docs: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html